# Are these two functions interchangeable under the integral sign?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have the following integral

$$ \int_a^b f(x)g(x)\,dx$$

now i see that

$$ \int_a^b f(x)\, dx = \int_a^b k(x)\,dx $$

where f(x) and g(x) are different functions.

as such is the following proposition correct?

$$ \int_a^b f(x)g(x) = \int_a^b k(x)g(x)\,dx $$

Thank you very much for your help and time. Apologies if the question is too basic.

Comment: sorry but no this is not valid in general

Answer (score 2):

Take $a=-1,b=1, f(x)=x, k(x)=-x, g(x)=x$ for a  counter-example.